# How can I set AllowAutoRedirect per request? Sharing HttpClient in multithreaded environment

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dotnet-httpclient

I'm little confused about HttpClient. At the moment I'm using single instance of this class in my whole application.

However it seems, that it doesn't allow me to set, for example AllowAutoRedirect option specifically for some requests.

Is HttpClient designed to be instantiated for every other request? I'm talking about multithreaded environment. Maybe I should wrap it in more flexible class structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change any properties per request, then yes, you will need to create a new instance of `HttpClient`. Obviously, performance and resources can play a factor if you're building a high-performance application with many requests due to creating the object multiple times.

Creating a wrapper class for `HttpClient` would be beneficial if you do go down this route and in any case, you can pass `HttpClient` as a parameter if you wish to change to a single instance.

`HttpClient` in most cases should be used as one instance as you can call as many requests as you like and the object has all the tools to handle async and responses. This is the same for request types `WebRequest` and `HttpWebRequest`.

If you need to receive a 200 OK status before starting another, managing those situations is extremely easy with one instance compared to creating your own queue functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered this question [in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76392591/3230716).

```
//Usage:
var handler = new RedirectHandler(new HttpClientHandler());
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

//redirects to HTTPS
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";

//AutoRedirect is true
var response = await HttpClientHelper.SendAsync(client, url, autoRedirect: true).ConfigureAwait(false);
//AutoRedirect is false
response = await HttpClientHelper.SendAsync(client, url, autoRedirect: false).ConfigureAwait(false);

public static class HttpClientHelper
{
    private const string AutoRedirectPropertyKey = "RequestAutoRedirect";
    private static readonly HttpRequestOptionsKey<bool?> AutoRedirectOptionsKey = new(AutoRedirectPropertyKey);

    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpClient client, string url, bool autoRedirect = true)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = uri,
            Method = HttpMethod.Get
        };
        
        request.SetAutoRedirect(autoRedirect);

        return client.SendAsync(request);
    }

    public static void SetAutoRedirect(this HttpRequestMessage request, bool autoRedirect)
    {
        request.Options.Set(AutoRedirectOptionsKey, autoRedirect);
    }
    public static bool? GetAutoRedirect(this HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        request.Options.TryGetValue(AutoRedirectOptionsKey, out var value);
        return value;
    }

    public static HttpMessageHandler? GetMostInnerHandler(this HttpMessageHandler? self)
    {
        while (self is DelegatingHandler handler)
        {
            self = handler.InnerHandler;
        }

        return self;
    }
}

public class RedirectHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private int MaxAutomaticRedirections { get; set; }
    private bool InitialAutoRedirect { get; set; }

    public RedirectHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler)
    {
        var mostInnerHandler = innerHandler.GetMostInnerHandler();
        SetupCustomAutoRedirect(mostInnerHandler);
    }

    private void SetupCustomAutoRedirect(HttpMessageHandler? mostInnerHandler)
    {
        //Store the initial auto-redirect & max-auto-redirect values.
        //Disabling auto-redirect and handle redirects manually.
        try
        {
            switch (mostInnerHandler)
            {
                case HttpClientHandler hch:
                    InitialAutoRedirect = hch.AllowAutoRedirect;
                    MaxAutomaticRedirections = hch.MaxAutomaticRedirections;
                    hch.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                    break;
                case SocketsHttpHandler shh:
                    InitialAutoRedirect = shh.AllowAutoRedirect;
                    MaxAutomaticRedirections = shh.MaxAutomaticRedirections;
                    shh.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    Debug.WriteLine("[SetupCustomAutoRedirect] Unknown handler type: {0}", mostInnerHandler?.GetType().FullName);
                    InitialAutoRedirect = true;
                    MaxAutomaticRedirections = 17;
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            InitialAutoRedirect = true;
            MaxAutomaticRedirections = 17;
        }
    }

    private bool IsRedirectAllowed(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var value = request.GetAutoRedirect();
        if (value == null)
            return InitialAutoRedirect;
        
        return value == true;
    }
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var redirectCount = 0;
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        //Manual Redirect
        //https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ccfe21882e4a2206ce49cd5b32d3eb3cab3e530f/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/RedirectHandler.cs
        Uri? redirectUri;
        while (IsRedirect(response) && IsRedirectAllowed(request) && (redirectUri = GetUriForRedirect(request.RequestUri!, response)) != null)
        {
            redirectCount++;
            if (redirectCount > MaxAutomaticRedirections)
                break;

            response.Dispose();

            // Clear the authorization header.
            request.Headers.Authorization = null;
            // Set up for the redirect
            request.RequestUri = redirectUri;

            if (RequestRequiresForceGet(response.StatusCode, request.Method))
            {
                request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
                request.Content = null;
                if (request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked == true)
                    request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = false;
            }

            // Issue the redirected request.
            response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return response;
    }
    private bool IsRedirect(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {
            case HttpStatusCode.MultipleChoices:
            case HttpStatusCode.Moved:
            case HttpStatusCode.Found:
            case HttpStatusCode.SeeOther:
            case HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect:
            case HttpStatusCode.PermanentRedirect:
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    private static Uri? GetUriForRedirect(Uri requestUri, HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        var location = response.Headers.Location;
        if (location == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Ensure the redirect location is an absolute URI.
        if (!location.IsAbsoluteUri)
        {
            location = new Uri(requestUri, location);
        }

        // Per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.2, a redirect location without a
        // fragment should inherit the fragment from the original URI.
        var requestFragment = requestUri.Fragment;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestFragment))
        {
            var redirectFragment = location.Fragment;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectFragment))
            {
                location = new UriBuilder(location) { Fragment = requestFragment }.Uri;
            }
        }

        return location;
    }
    private static bool RequestRequiresForceGet(HttpStatusCode statusCode, HttpMethod requestMethod)
    {
        switch (statusCode)
        {
            case HttpStatusCode.Moved:
            case HttpStatusCode.Found:
            case HttpStatusCode.MultipleChoices:
                return requestMethod == HttpMethod.Post;
            case HttpStatusCode.SeeOther:
                return requestMethod != HttpMethod.Get && requestMethod != HttpMethod.Head;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea is to disable automatic redirects and handle them manually using a custom **RedirectHandler**.

1. Before sending a request, we utilize the extension method **SetAutoRedirect** to store the redirect rule in the request's options dictionary.
2. Upon receiving a response, we check if it is a redirect. If it is, we then examine the request's options dictionary for a redirect rule using the extension method **GetAutoRedirect**.
3. Repeat #2 until **MaxAutomaticRedirections** is reached or there are no further redirects.